# Using boost buffer to serialize and send using UDP protocol

Tags: c++, boost, udp

I want to serialize and send some data through UDP protocol. Code looks as below:

```
typedef struct{
   uint8_t a[2];
   uint8_t b;
}example;
std::vector<example> ex_vector; //Filling part of this vector is notgiven here

void sendUDP(){
    int sockfd;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in serv;

    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port = htons(5005);
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    //const uint8_t buffer[2] = {0x12, 0x13}; -> Works well with this
    auto mutable_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(ex_vector);
    socklen_t m = sizeof(serv);
    sendto(sockfd,mutable_buffer,sizeof(mutable_buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *)&serv,m);
}
```

How can I serialize the vector of POD element (`example`) using boost ? Code for UDP is taken from (http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/76180/).

Currently error pops up:

```
no matching function for call to 'sendto'
    sendto(sockfd,mutable_buffer,sizeof(mutable_buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *)&serv,m);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`boost::asio::buffer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html):

> The contents of a buffer may be accessed using the data() and size() member functions:
>
> ```
> boost::asio::mutable_buffer b1 = ...;
> std::size_t s1 = b1.size();
> unsigned char* p1 = static_cast<unsigned char*>(b1.data());
> ```

(Though, I wonder why you are mixing boost and posix, boost has `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket` that should flawlessly work with the buffer and examples should be available on the internet)